# virtualenv doesnt find installed module when running tests [Pytest]

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, virtualenv, pytest

I'm writing my first test for a class where I imported an external packages ( installed via pip in the venv ).
I'm using PyCharm as an IDE and it the package in question is listed there under the project interpreter ( the venv ) as well as when I type `pip freeze` in console.
Now I want to `run` a `run-tests.sh` file and when my test is reached `pytest` is returning me an `ERROR` : `E ImportError: No module named 'magic'`

The code line which fails the test is obviously the import statement in my class which I want to test.

Any ideas?

//Edit: 
*for clarification:* **NOT the terminal itself is throwing the Error! `PYTEST` does!**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make sure that you have installed packages through pycharm, if it don't list your package, it means that you install your package in other place, go to file > setting > project:[NAME] >interpreter to check it. then yo can use "+" to install package

Comment: like i stated above the packages in question is listed in PyCharm as well

Answer (score 0):

fixed it myself. for some dubious reason pytest and my venv did have a problem. reinstalled pytest within my virtual env via `pip install pytest`